# Error ActivateApplication in my Windows Cordova application

Tags: windows, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to get the blank app working on the windows platform. I did the following:

```
ionic start myApp blank
cd .\myApp\
ionic platform add windows
ionic emulate windows
```

them I'm getting the following exception:

```
Starting application...
ActivateApplication:  com.ionicframework.myappmework.myapp781
Ausnahme beim Aufrufen von "ActivateApplication" mit 4 Argument(en):  "Der Remoteprozeduraufruf ist fehlgeschlagen.
(Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x800706BE)"
In C:\...\myApp\platforms\windows\cordova\lib\WindowsStoreAppUtils.ps1:164 Zeichen:5
+     $appActivator.ActivateApplication($applicationUserModelId,$null,[ ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : COMException
```

What I need to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `ionic run windows -- --win` to deploy to windows.
`ionic run windows -- --phone` to launch application on emulator. And `ionic run windows --device -- --phone` to launch on real device. 
Plus if you still get failed then run `ionic run windows --list` to see if there is any target(emulator or device) available or not.

Comment: was a fix ever found for this?

Comment: I am still getting the error.. I worked in basically more in android and ios this is my first build in windows .. can anyone help me out.. I am not sure simulators are installed or not.. dont know how to check [

Answer (score 2):

Be sure the Windows 10 SDK is installed. In your config.xml add the following entry:

```
<preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" />
```

That should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue with an app and it could not be related to my cordova or SDK installation, as another app worked perfectly fine.

In my case, it was related to **JavaScript errors**. First, I updated jQuery to the latest version, which made the error message vanish. However, the app would still crash directly after starting it up, which was related to another JS-error (as seen in the JS console when running it in a browser). Fixing this made it finally work as expected.