# Cordova run windows this error - Exception calling "ActivateApplication" with "4" argument(s):

Tags: cordova

Cordova run Windows throws the following error:

> Success: Your app was successfully installed.
>   Starting application...
>   ActivateApplication:  com.xyz.abc
>   Exception calling "ActivateApplication" with "4" argument(s): "The
>   remote procedure call failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BE)"

NOTE: I have installed Windows 10 SDK (Standalone) and also from VS2015.
I have **Windows 10 SDK 10.0.14393.33** and **Windows 10 SDK 10.0.10586.212** installed on my system.

I also tried *cordova run windows --target="Mobile Emulator 10.0.14393.0 WVGA 4 inch 1GB"* but got this error:

> Error: Deploying desktop apps to specific target not supported

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error ActivateApplication in my Windows Cordova application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32480978/error-activateapplication-in-my-windows-cordova-application)

Comment: Didn't work for me.